# Parsing XML Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, newline

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse an XML file. I have a problem. I do not know how to obtain a plain text line between tags.

```
<Sync time="4.496"/>
<Background time="4.496" type="music" level="high"/>

<Event desc="pause" type="noise" extent="instantaneous"/>
Plain text
<Sync time="7.186"/>

<Event desc="b" type="noise" extent="instantaneous"/>
Plain text
<Sync time="10.949"/>
Plain text
```

I have this code already:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os

data_file = "./file.xml"

xmlD = etree.parse(data_file)
root = xmlD.getroot()
sections = root.getchildren()[2].getchildren()
for section in sections:
    turns = section.getchildren()
    for turn in turns:
        speaker = turn.get('speaker')
    mode = turn.get('mode')
    childs = turn.getchildren()

        for child in childs:
            time = child.get('time')
            opt = child.get('desc')
            if opt == 'es':
                 opt = "ESP:"
            elif opt == "la":
                 opt = "LATIN:"
            elif opt == "*":
                 opt = "-ININT-"
            elif opt == "fs":
                 opt = "-FS-"
            elif opt == "throat":
                 opt = "-THROAT-"
            elif opt == "laugh":
                 opt = "-LAUGH-"
            else:
                 opt = ""

            print speaker, mode, time, opt+child.tail.encode('latin-1')
```

I can access through the XML until the Sync|Background|Event tag, and can't extract the text after these tags. I put a piece of the XML file, no the entire file. I only have problems with the final piece of code

Thank you so much @alecxe . Now I can get the info that I needed. But now I have a new little problem. I obtain the line typing the `tail` command but a newline character `\n` is generated before or something similar, so, I need something like:
`spk1 planned  LAN: Plain text from tail`>

But I get this:

`spk1 planned  LAN:
Plain text from tail`

I have tried many things, `re.match()` module, `sed` commands after processing the XML, but it seems there is no `\n` new line character, but I can't  "put up" the plain text! Thank you in advance

Anyone? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a [`tail` of an element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail):

> The tail attribute can be used to hold additional data associated with
>   the element. This attribute is usually a string but may be any
>   application-specific object. If the element is created from an XML
>   file the attribute will contain any **text found after the element’s end
>   tag and before the next tag**.

Locate the `Event` tag and get the tail, example:

```
section.find("Event").tail
```